# How do I change the kernel bandwidth used in a density plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I see what bandwidth gets used for kernels in a density plot and how do I specify a bandwidth to be used?  I tried

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg))+geom_density(bw=1)
```

with no luck.

Comment: Just read `?stat_density` which in turn points you to `density`.

Comment: @joran Aha, thanks.  I needed the "adjust" parameter.  So, how do I see what bandwidth actually gets used in a density plot?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to see that other than calculating it yourself separately, e.g. using `bw.nrd0`.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment, but just to add to the previous answers: as Joran hinted, in addition to using "adjust", there are several alternative functions that can be used to calculate bandwidth: see [this ggplot documentation](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density.html) and [this bandwidth page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.3/topics/bandwidth) for specifics. Note the syntax: to select the `bw.nrd` function, for example, you want `density(x,bw = "nrd")`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`stat_geom` utilises the `adjust` argument to apply a multiplier to the optimal bandwidth that ggplot calculates see [documentation for `density()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/density.html).  Try:

`ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg))+geom_density() + stat_density(adjust = 2)`

I gather to determine the calculated optimal bandwidth - based on *"the standard deviation of the smoothing kernel"* - you'll need to interrogate Venables, W. N. and Ripley, B. D. (2002) Modern Applied Statistics with S. New York: Springer.

Comment: Right MASSe4 index has p 128 as the place to look and the discussion proceeds for a couple more pages.

Comment: When I apply `+ stat_density(adjust=2)` to a geom_density with transparency (`alpha=0.5`), I lose the transparency. Any thoughts?

Comment: `ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg)) + stat_density(adjust = 2, alpha=0.5)`
If that's not what you want please give your full line and explain what outcome you're looking for

Comment: @JoseR `stat_density` will add a new `geom_density` on top of your old one. You can use `geom_density(adjust = 2)` directly, since extra arguments to `geom_density` are passed to the underlying `stat_density`.