# ggplot2 log-scale on x-axis is jacking up my geom_density kernel

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density

StackOverflowers!  I am trying to illustrate a comparison of distributions on the log10 scale, with data that sort of look like this:

```
df <- data.frame( grp = c( rep('A',1e5), rep('B',1e5), rep('C',1e5) ),
                  qty = c( rpois(1e5,5), rpois(1e5,25), rpois(1e5,50) ) + 1 )
```

My issue (I think) is that the [default](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_density.html) gaussian kernel for `geom_density` does not handle this scale well.  It produces this saw-toothed look which is not so smooth.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(qty, fill=grp)) + 
  scale_x_log10(limits=c(1,100), breaks=c(1:10,25,50)) +
  geom_density(alpha=.3)+
  ylab("Density") + xlab("Count of Things") +
  ggtitle("Density of Quantity of Things by Group")
```

[image]

(I added the tick marks to elucidate the problem.  Removing them does nothing.)

I think I am looking for a kernel with a variance that decreases exponentially with x, so that it's constant width in log-x... is this possible?

I have also tried `geom_histogram(...stat='density')` which does the same thing.  I also tried `+ coord_trans(xtrans="log10")` instead of `+ scale_log10()` but it didn't solve the problem and does something funky to the y-axis.  Gratiations!

Comment: `geom_density(alpha=.3, adjust=5)` looks better, but I'm not a stat person

Comment: @baptiste Thanks for this, which led me to this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755265/how-do-i-change-the-kernel-bandwidth-used-in-a-density-plot-in-r). I would accept your comment-answer as a viable workaround in the absence of a more specific solution.  By the power vested in me by the internet, I hereby declare you a "stat person."  Arise.