# How to put geom_density and geom_histogram on same counts scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am wanting to put `geom_histogram` and `geom_density` on the same scale. I can accomplish this in one direction by using `geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(density)))`. This works great if I want everything on the density scale. However, I am wanting things on the count scale. But adding `geom_density(aes(y = stat(count)))` results in a density line that is not on the same scale as the counts in the histogram. Is there a way to get both density and histogram on the same count scale?

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = rnorm(10000))

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(density))) +
  geom_density()
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  geom_density(aes(y = stat(count)))
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [geom_density to match geom_histogram binwitdh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404002/geom-density-to-match-geom-histogram-binwitdh). Use `ggplot(df,aes(x))+
      geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5)+
      geom_density(aes(y=0.5 * ..count..))`

Comment: I know little about this, but look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755265/how-do-i-change-the-kernel-bandwidth-used-in-a-density-plot-in-r) and try to change this argument `geom_density(aes(y = stat(count)), adjust = 25)`,  if the above comment does not satisfy you.