# How to plot "difficult" probability distributions with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density, probability-density

### Background

Certain probability distributions such as quotient distributions (aka [ratio distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution)), a specific case of which is the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution), seem to be difficult to visualise because of their heavy tails. Here is a MRE in `ggplot2`:

```
require(ggplot2)
a <- rnorm(1e4, 2, 0.5)
b <- rnorm(1e4, 0.2, 0.1)
c <- a/b
ggplot() + geom_density(aes(c)) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-300, 500))
```

[image]

### Question

I have tried adjusting the kernel bandwidth following answers to [this S/O post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755265/how-do-i-change-the-kernel-bandwidth-used-in-a-density-plot-in-r) but that didn't seem to work. How do I get a smooth version of the above probability distribution? The same problem obviously arises when I try working with dependencies, such as `ggridges::geom_density_ridges`.

Comment: As a small side note, you might want to be careful naming your variables `c` in R, as it is also the widely used function to combine things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that ggplot2 by default creates 512 points along the x-axis over which to evaluate the kernel density. Since your range is fraction of the data range, only a a few of those evaluated points will be shown. We can demonstrate this by adding a point layer:

```r
library(ggplot2)
a <- rnorm(1e4, 2, 0.5)
b <- rnorm(1e4, 0.2, 0.1)
c <- a/b

ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(c), stat = "density") +
  geom_density(aes(c)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-300, 500))
```

[image]

Of note, density layer does not know about the coord's limits. One way to remedy the issue, is to increase the number of points with the `n` argument.

```r
# Increase number of points over which to evaluate density
ggplot() + 
  geom_density(aes(c), n = 10000) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-300, 500))
```

[image]

However, this can be inefficient as you're not using all these points. Instead, you can set the scale's limits, which the density layer *will* know about. This will make the range you're looking at more densely populated with points, giving a smoother KDE.

An important detail here is that we're using `oob = scales::oob_keep` as the out-of-bounds handler. This ensures that the KDE calculation considers all points, not just the ones in your range.

```r
# Limit range to populate with points over which to evaluate density
ggplot() + 
  geom_density(aes(c)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-300, 500), 
                     oob = scales::oob_keep) # Do not censor data
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @teunbrand, this is a great solution for `stat_density`. However, it does not work for `ggridges::stat_density_ridges` (no change in KDE) and only partially works for `ggdist::stat_slab` (change in KDE but not smooth). Any thoughts?

Comment: For `ggridges::stat_density_ridges()`, you can set the from/to arguments without setting any limits outside that function. For `ggdist::stat_slab()` I don't know. Intuitively, I'd have thought you could use the `limits` argument there, but it seems to be ignored.

Comment: Sorry to return to my query at such a late stage @teunbrand, but I recently bumped into the above problem with `geom_split_violin()` using code from @Trang Q. Nguyen (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74895850/14715716). The `oob = scales::oob_keep` solution does not work and `geom_violin()` and its derivatives don't have an `n` argument. Perhaps you have an idea? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: No I can't come up with a simple solution in this case, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick reply @teunbrand. In that case I am working on a solution with the answer provided by @Axeman (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35719046/14715716). Since it converts densities to polygons, the `oob` trick comes at too late a stage (the plotting stage). Would you recommend increasing the `n` or constraining the `from`/`to` arguments when the densities are estimated? Does it make a difference? Does constraining `from`/`to` still use the entire distribution?